# .NET core backend, model with Required nullable being created from Postman without required data sent in

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I have a model with the following property:

```
[Required]
public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

This is Required and nullable, which is excactly what I want, trying to avoid empty or default date set, forcing user/frontend to send a date.

My Dto has no annotations and the property is not nullable:

```
public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody] InputDto input)
{
    var creatInputId = await inputService.AddAsync(input);
    return Ok(creatInputId );
}
```

Service maps Dto to model using Automapper:

```
var input = _mapper.Map<InputModel>(inputDto);
```

When I test this controller from Postman, database is updated whether I supply a CreatedDate or not, from frontend it does not. When using Postman, CreatedDate in database is set to 01-01-0001.

Should I use dataannotations in my Dto as well? I want to avoid default date/prohibit saving input unless a non-default date is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Dto` gets hit before the model. As it is not required or nullable it is filled with default value which is quite similar to `01-01-0001` in case of `DateTime`.

You need to put your annotations in the `Dto` also.

Comment: Perfect, thank you